# How Ethereum network could adhere to EU's GDPR when it is a public (not private) blockchain

Tags: ethereum, privacy

Correct me if I'm wrong, GDPR states that personal data of an EU citizen must stays inside EU. But Ethereum nodes are located globally.

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right. Public blockchains like ethereum simply can not ensure the standards of the GDPR.
Apart from the localization of the data, another big problem is Art. 17 of the GDPR, the `right to be forgotten`. Which states that the user has the right to erasure of his data. This also doesn't work in a public blockchain like ethereum.
Once your data is in the blockchain, it stays there.

The GDPR was developed with conventional data storages in mind. A lot of it simply doesn't work with the technology of a public blockchain.